# Is the Firebase Realtime limit on Write rate per second

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, real-time

The Firebase documentation on [Realtime Database limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#writes) contains this limit for writes:

Write rate:
1,000 writes/second

If I exceed the limit of 1,000 write operations per second for a single database instance in Firebase Realtime Database, will it throw an exception or will the requests be queued?

Comment: When the write limit is exceeded, the server will respond with a status code indicating that the request has been rejected due to the limit being exceeded.

Comment: Is this 1,000 writes/second is for individual user?? or overall users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reach 1,000 writes/second, the Firebase servers will throw a [DatabaseException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseException) that will contain a message that indicates that you exceeded the limit of 1,000 writes/second. To solve this, you can evaluate the message in the catch clause and then create another Realtime Database instance.

Comment: Hey Muhammad. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: yeah it helps but is this 1,000 writes/second is for individual user?? or overall users?

Comment: For all users that access that Realtime Database instance.

Comment: Okay! Is this limitation is also for firebase admin-sdk or only for client sdk?

Comment: For both admin and client SDKs.